# Does this statement constitute various fallacies? Is my delineation correct?

Tags: fallacies

Person 1:"Man, J____, M____, and L____ tend to work at a cumbersome pace."

**Person 2:"Yeah, they're lazy, obviously"***

- LJ, M & L share similar characteristics in terms of skin color. They also appear to be from the same ethnic group and/or race.
- I don't know person2's reasoning behind HIS/HER claim

What I called: genetic fallacy (Composition) BECAUSE of the assertion/semantics of 'common sense". Assuming I know where person2 might be coming from in terms of reasoning and from what is known, is this correct? Why or why not? Am I committing a fallacy myself (fallacy fallacy)?

Comment: @TKol. Roberto~~ My answer (below) assumes that Person2 is making an over generalization of some sort. Was I correct? TKol suggested that I ask you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Does this statement constitute several fallacies?**

Yes, there are at least two problems with the reasoning by Person 2.

The first is Guilt by Association. This fallacy is typically AAA in the second figure: All P are M; All S are M; therefore All S are P. The problem is the undistributed middle term; there is nothing to connect the two premises.

A second might be Hasty Generalization. Person 2 has drawn a conclusion about a group of people based on the observation of only three of its members.

*Am I committing a fallacy myself (fallacy fallacy)?*

No. It looks like you spotted the problem; you just did not have a name for it.

Comment: I have no idea what you think person 2 said that's eliciting this response from you. Person 2 just said "obviously those 3 people are lazy". What aspect of what person 2 said, in your view, is a hasty generalization, or guilt by association or whatever?

Comment: @TKoL. My answer assumes that the comment about’ the same ethnic group and/or race’ had some relevance to the question.

Comment: And the immediately following statement after that is "I don't know person2's reasoning behind HIS/HER claim". OP has no idea if person 2's reasoning is on account of their ethnic group.

Comment: @TKol. Then it makes no sense to ask whether any fallacy applies to the statement.

Comment: Yes! That's the correct answer. Calling a statement 'fallacious' when you have no idea about any of the reasoning behind it is nonsense.

Comment: @TKoL.  Then what was the purpose of the words ‘genetic fallacy (Composition)’?

Comment: Ask the person who said it.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it's not a full statement... Like seriously you need a full implication for a fallacy, if it's not even clear what these people are talking about you or what they dog whistle, then it's impossible to call that a fallacy... Like at the very least make the full hypothetical statement of what they were saying like "if they made the implication of XYZ that would that be a fallacy".

I  mean for all intents and purposes the "obvious" fact that he's talking about could be that they "work at a cumbersome pace" compared to other human beings their age, ability and medical status. So he assumes it's a matter of motivation.

In other words that would be an affirmation and rephrasing of what person1 has said with a little more implication in terms of the cause.

But sure person2 and potentially also person1 could also be racist, xenophobic or whatnot and try to make a statement of all X are lazy, J.,M.,L., are X, therefore J.,M.,L. are lazy. Now it's important that this wouldn't be a fallacy. But a valid statement. Which DOES NOT mean that it is true. In fact it doesn't mean that anything about this argument needs to be true. It just means that if it were to be true that all X are lazy and J.,M.,L., are X then J.,M.,L., WOULD be lazy.

So you'd need to first of all define what "lazy" and "cumbersome pace" mean in quantifiable terms and you'd need to prove that indeed all X are that. And unless you make these definitions ridiculous or do foul play in terms of coercing people and act surprised if they don't give you their best, you'll likely find that the first premise is simply not true and so the statement is valid but not sound (valid and the premises are true). Potentially not even the second premise is true, as just because you apply this kind of categorization, doesn't mean that this makes sense to begin with.

But you might still commit the fallacy fallacy in that if they were racist and make this racist statement, then just because their reasoning is bullshit, doesn't mean that J.,M.,L., can't still be lazy. Wouldn't have anything to do with their race or ethnicity, but just about them individually.

The point of validity is that the conclusion must follow from the premises, the point of soundness is that the argument is valid and that the premises are true, hence the conclusion would be true. But that doesn't mean that a conclusion isn't true just because the statement isn't valid, all it means is that it's not true because of the reasons that you've stated it to be true for. In other words it's not really a "conclusion" that follows from the premises but just an unrelated bit of information.